# Why hash of private data should be shared on hyperledger-fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I read 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/private-data/private-data.html says that

"A hash of that data, which is endorsed, ordered, and written to the ledgers of every peer on the channel. The hash serves as evidence of the transaction and is used for state validation and can be used for audit purposes."  .

However, I think signatures of the transaction is enough for evidence that contract was agreed upon.

Why hash of the data should be shared among the every peers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private transactions are not stored in blocks in the chain like public transactions. All the peers joined to the channel share the same channel chain. Thus, if the private transaction were stored normally in the chain, every peer (even those from organizations to which the transaction is not destined) could read the private transaction parameters (and reconstruct the others' private state). To avoid this, basically, a hash is stored in the block in its place so that the organizations which share the private data can still check integrity.

---

**EDIT:**

Let's see, if you read carefully https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/private-data/private-data.html#transaction-flow-with-private-data, you'll see that at no time is the private data signed (neither the readset, nor the writeset, nor the input, nor the output). In step 3 a signature is produced only over its hash (embedded in the transaction). Nothing else. The private data (the data, not the transaction) is simply distributed via gossip protocol and stored temporally in the transient data store (point 2), to be committed in point 5. The only evidence on the private data is the hash (which is embedded in the transaction and signed). The gossip protocol has its security mechanisms, but it does not produce evidence or guarantee the transaction order.

Now, take the case where, later, a malicious organization unilaterally alters its private state in order to obtain some kind of benefit. That hash in the chain would be the only evidence left to resolve the dispute with other organizations. There is no other evidence on the agreed valid value (and the execution order) than that hash. No plain text private data was signed by the peer.

That's the way it is at Fabric. And it makes sense. Keep in mind that it is necessary to guarantee the integrity of the data and the order in which the transactions are executed, so at some point the orderer (point 4) has to be involved to determine the order (in most cases the order of the transactions does alter the product) without disclosing the real data.

Comment: I agree that every peer should not read the private transaction. 
However, It seems to me that sharing raw transaction with destined node and private state only is sufficient. Is there necessity for sharing hash with every peer and channel state.

Comment: But one of the strengths of blockchain is that there is a block chain (as its name says) that ensures integrity. If there is absolutely no trace of the private transactions in the chain (and you even proceed without the intervention of the ordering service) we cannot talk about blockchain. This method is not only used by Fabric. Quorum (a fork of Ethereum supporting privacy) works in a very similar way.

Comment: My question a bit cleared. Thank you. "Strength" is certainly high. I didn't think about strength. However, I feel something incompatible. 
Maybe, for truly being convinced of necessity of sharing hash, I need some attack example that can be prevented by sharing hash, and cannot be prevented if hash was not shared.

Comment: Thank you! very detailed perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I feel is that, when only signature is shared, how does other peers validate what the signature is for? Or vice versa, how to validate whether it is actually being signed by the claimed owner? So, we share hash of the transaction + signature of that hash. This signature now can be verified using public certificate of that owner. Also, as the transaction is hashed, it remains private but the ledger (blocks chained to one another) is identical among all peers.